# IBM Worklight 6.0 - application-descriptor.xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I recently migrated to Worklight Studio 6, and the application-descriptor.xml of my app is being flagged due to the width, height, and worklightServerRootURL elements.  I've looked in the documentation but haven't found a mention yet of how to migrate these elements for Worklight 6.  Are there replacements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned elements have been removed (`worklightServerRootURL`) and moved (`height`, `width` - into the Adobe Air element, if the environment exist in the project).

Your application-descriptor.xml should not flag you about these. If you do get flagged (do you mean you get an error or warning?), it means something in the upgrade process of your project has gone bad.

In any case, to overcome this simply remove the offending elements.
That said, because this could indicate on a bad upgrade other things may have gone wrong as well. If you can add any more information it will help.

Can you share your project? (export it as .zip file from Eclipse)

Comment: Thanks for the response!  For the worklightServerRootURL, how does the application now know which Worklight server to communicate with?  I see a mention in the docs of a worklightSettings element, but how does it initially know which server to use.

Comment: The server does some magic and knows to append the correct information to the application during build time...