# WL 6.0. How to generate apk or ipa pointing to the right server without the worklightServerRootURL

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have read the posts:

[IBM Worklight 6.0 - worklightserverhost attribute and the app-builder Ant task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682630/ibm-worklight-6-0-worklightserverhost-attribute-and-the-app-builder-ant-task/17683960#17683960)
[IBM Worklight - How to connect to another Worklight Server located in another machine in the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585522/ibm-worklight-how-to-connect-to-another-worklight-server-located-in-another-ma/17586294#17586294)
[IBM Worklight 6.0 - application-descriptor.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533781/ibm-worklight-6-0-application-descriptor-xml)

And I think I'm missing something because all them stop with the generation of the wlapp for other servers.

After generating and installing the wlapp it is needed to generate and apk/ipa or "Run As" over the environment to execute that application.

The problem I'm having is that the deployed application in the device points to the development server always and not to the other server I have used for generating the .wlapp files with the (Run As -> Build For Remote Server...).

I have tried deploying the application with the property "publicWorkLighHostname" changed in the worklight.properites but it has no effect.

How do I deploy an application to the device pointing to the desired server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Run As >> Build All and Deploy / Build specific environment, points to the local development server
- Build for Remote Server, points to a server of your choosing

If you perform a `Build All and Deploy` after a `Build for Remote Server`, this will overwrite the previous action and the artifacts will again point to the local development machine.

So do a Build for Remote Server. Worklight Studio knows where to put what so that the app will reach the server.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that the "Build for Remote Server" generted the .wlapp and also regenerate the environments projects... So after Buid for Remote Server I have to go directly to xCode or to the Android project and run it. Thank you.